# Get All of One (or More) Element's Attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a requirement to supply values from 2 select boxes to an Action Method. I'd like to know if there's a way to automatically extract all of the attributes from the selected options from each select box into a data object that I can pass to the server with my $.get?

Ideally, I could use a function like this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/6530

```
var data = $.getAttributes($('#lstFilter option:selected'))
```

this works perfectly for single element but this it's no good for multiple elements because it returns a json object that can't be appended to.

Can anyone suggest a work around or a different approach that i could take to get a result?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd best do this with [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var valuesArray = $("select").map(function() {
  return $(this).find(":selected").val();
});
```

The above returns an array of values. You may need to identify the source of each value, in which case you'll need something like:

```
var values = {};
$("#select").each(function() {
  values[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).find(":selected").val();
});
```

which creates an anonymous object of all the `<select>` values.