# Model Binding is Failing when I pass JSON via $.get()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

This question is related to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378836/get-all-of-one-or-more-elements-attributes-with-jquery).

I'm using the following to extract the attributes & values from the select elements on my page:

```
var valuesArray = $("select").map(function()
{
    return $.getAttributes($(this).find(":selected"));
});

var arr = new Array();
$.each(valuesArray, function()
{
    arr.push($(this)[0]); // this filters out things like 'length'
});
```

basically, after I get an array of the objects representing the attributes of my select boxes, I want to convert that to a data string that I can pass to the server

```
// get data string for server
var data = $.toJSON(arr);
```

The JSON returned is:

```
[{"siteId":"2"},{"filterId":"2","factSheetPanelId":"2"}]
```

and I pass it to the server like so:

```
$.get(url, data, function(result)
{
    // do stuff
}, "html");
```

The code on the server is but it's not picking up the values & Model Binding is failing

```
public PartialViewResult PanelList(FactsheetPanel panel, Site site)
{
    // panel.FactsheetPanelId == 0. I would expect it to be 2
    // same for site.SiteId..
}
```

Can anyone see anyting obviously wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass JSON. jQuery will simply pass that to the server, which won't know what to do with it unless you write a JSON data binder.

Instead, pass a JavaScript object. jQuery will serialize that into query string parameters, which work correctly. E.g.:

```
var data = {
               panel: { filterId: "2", factSheetPanelId: "2" },
               site: { siteId: "2" }
           };
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks wrong. It would have helped if you also posted your `FactsheetPanel` and `Site` classes but anyway, as far as I understand, here's how your JSON should be after getting the values from your HTML elements and processing them.

```
{"site.siteId":"2", "panel.filterId":"2","panel.factSheetPanelId":"2"}
```