# Src of all images with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, src

I want the `src` of all images from a div (lets call it `"#all_imgs"`) in one simple array.

The array should look like this:

```
["http://src.de/3792282714_90584b41d5_b.jpg", 
 "http://src.de/1402810863_d41f360b2e_o.jpg"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try *anything*? Have you had a look at the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Seriously; With jQuery, this is simple, really simple. Read http://api.jquery.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get All of One (or More) Element's Attributes with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378836/get-all-of-one-or-more-elements-attributes-with-jquery)

Comment: Really everyone?  While simple, the question is legitimate.  Instead of griefing the poster, why not just post the solution if it is so simple?  I'm not sure why there is so much anger about this post.

Comment: @Brian: I didn't down vote but I assume it is because this sounds like a "give-me-teh-codez" question. I'm thinking especially about the "Do your homework" section in [ask]. I'm missing this here... but I agree that it does not deserver that many down votes.

Comment: @Felix Bah, where'd the tag go?  ;)  
I suppose I'm just a bit upset that so many programmers either 1) Forget what it was like to be a new programmer, or 2) Forget that Stack Overflow is as much a repository of Q/A's as it is a place to get help for difficult/annoying coding questions.  The question kind of edges close to the "Do your homework" section, but hits the rest well.

Comment: @Brian: I can understand you. Of course it should be also a site for "simple" question. But what makes me upset is if I have  the feeling the poster did not attempt anything at all. This somehow implies that he wants us to do his work. But this way, one cannot learn anything. And for me, this site has also a *teaching* purpose. In today's times, people want things fast and without any effort... I think I'm becoming off topic. Maybe I just had enough SO for today ;)

Comment: Sorry guys, don't wanted to start something big here. Seems like I searched for the wrong stuff and this solution is really simpler than I thought. Works fine now.

Comment: @tobi: No worries. I didn't want to offend you. If I did, I'm sorry. After some time one just gets a bit tired of questions that show no effort in solving the problem (again, no offense). But I will work on this :) Just as a tip: Next time, include *any* of your attempts to solve the problem, no matter how wrong they are (or at least explain them). This shows that you really tried something and not just expect us to do something for you.

Comment: @Felix I can understand why you are tired. It's no problem :)

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted. With jQuery there's about a dozen ways of doing the same thing, but usually one method is more elegant than the other, and in some cases certain methods should be avoided. Though I agree the question appears to show little effort.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var arr = $('#all_imgs img').map(function() { return this.src; }).get()
```

Comment: You are too nice ;) They will never learn :( But maybe it's just because I'm tired...

Comment: @Felix: I was feeling the same way the other day. I figure it was 10 seconds out of my day to type up an answer. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: You are right. Maybe I accumulated to many of these `10 seconds` today (or recently). Time for a SO break :) (which I probably cannot go through with ;))

Comment: @Felix: Plus, it's +10 rep for an answer :)

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, it's surprisingly hard to break away. I completely understand the frustration too. I'll sometimes spend *days* trying to figure out a problem, and will learn 10 new things along the way. Other people I've seen on StackOverflow (not referring to @tobi) want every little thing spoon fed to them. Different personality types I guess.

Comment: @Brian: Sadly, I reached my daily rep cap half a day ago. I've missed out on about 150 rep form up-votes, but still I persist. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: Frustation was the right word. It didn't came to my mind (although it is actually the same in German...). And  I'm still here....tstst. Thanks for the support or at least shared grief or whatever-you-call-it. You are a greatEnjoy your day! :)

Comment: @Felix: Always willing to offer some empathy to a friend on SO. You enjoy your day too. :o)

Answer (score 1):

`var images = $("img").map(function () { return this.src; });`